# v-if not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have a Vue component that I want to appear sometimes in one spot, sometimes in another. So I give it a property which I test in a v-if directive on the root of template. I have two custom tags in my markup, and assume that I'll get two distinct instances of my component. To my surprise, the component renders twice, even when one of the properties is false. What is going on here?

**markup**

```
<div id='vueRoot'>
  <now-you-see-me show-me='true'></now-you-see-me>
  <now-you-see-me show-me='false'></now-you-see-me>
</div>
```

**js**

```
Vue.component('now-you-see-me',{
  template : `<div v-if='showMe'>I only want ONE **{{showMe}}**</div`,
  props : ['showMe']
})
vm = new Vue({
  el : '#vueRoot'
})
```

[running here](https://jsfiddle.net/aw3bup8u/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `true` and `false` bindings, you have to use `v-bind:show-me` instead of just `show-me`, because the attribute's value will otherwise be evaluated as a string instead of a boolean exprsesion, e.g.:

```
<now-you-see-me v-bind:show-me='true'></now-you-see-me>
```

...or if you're more comfortable with shorthands:

```
<now-you-see-me :show-me='true'></now-you-see-me>
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
Vue.component('now-you-see-me',{
  template : `<div v-if='showMe'>I only want ONE **{{showMe}}**</div>`,
  props : ['showMe']
})
vm = new Vue({
  el : '#vueRoot'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='vueRoot'>
  <now-you-see-me :show-me='true'></now-you-see-me>
  <now-you-see-me :show-me='false'></now-you-see-me>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `show-me` property as a string, when you actually want to pass it as a boolean. Instead of `show-me="..."` write `v-bind:show-me="..."` (or `:show-me="..."`). Everything inside the `"` then will be interpreted as Javascript instead of a string.

https://jsfiddle.net/aw3bup8u/1/

Comment: Damn, to slow :/